# NetSuite - using "anyof" with multiple parameters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to have a searchFilter in a script that would put in many parameters for internalid. For example, my code for the filter is below. An example for the values of listIds is "11276, 1234, 7895".

What I am trying to figure out is what format listIds should be if I want the above input? Do I need csv values or an array or something else?

I can't find anything in SuiteAnswers or Stackoverflow for this. I am going to just try an array first (which is my gut instinct) and see from there but was hoping to save some time. If I determine the answer, I will be posting it for others.

```js
var listIDs = "11276, 1234, 7895";
var a_filters = [];
a_filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', listIDs));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `anyOf` or `noneOf`, you need to use an Array, not just a String. So, your `listIDs` needs to be

```
var listIDs = ["11276", "1234", "7895"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write like this:

```
filters: ['internalid', 'ANY', ["1397","1251"]]
```

Comment: If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the docs correctly, you are actually supposed to use `is` for the `internalid` (since it is not a `select` value).  I would rewrite as:

```
var filters = [ 'internalid', 'is', [ 11276, 1234, 7895 ] ];
nlapiSearchRecord(recordType, null, filters, null);
```

Comment: You can use `is` if you are only looking for a single ID: `['internalid', 'is', '11276']`